# Is there a pattern/trick to enforce '<:' when defining type aliases with '='

Tags: scala, refinement-type

I ran into another issue of scala's subtype relation being non transitive (https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/12164) and I start to think if there is some general work around possible. Long story short:

```
trait Thing { thisThing =>
    type Super >: Self <: Thing {
        type Super <: thisThing.Super
    }
    type Self <: Thing {
        type Super = thisThing.Super
        type Self = thisThing.Self
    }
}

trait Wrapper extends Thing {
    type SuperAdapted >: Adapted <: Thing
    type Adapted <: Thing
}

trait Adapter[+T <: Thing] extends Wrapper {
    val thing :T
    type Super = Adapter[thing.Super]
    type Self = Adapter[thing.Self]
    type Adapted = thing.Self
}

type Universal[+T <: Thing] = Wrapper { type Adapted <: T }
```

And this does not compile:

```
val t :Thing
implicitly[Adapter[t.Super] <:< Universal[t.Super]]
```

Now I have `T <: Thing { type General <: G }` but not `Adapter[T] <:< Universal[G]`.
Is there a way to work around it? One would be of course to unitilize `<:<#liftCo`, but it works only for values, not types, and prevents higher types from using `Adapter[T]` and retaining a proper subtyping relation - basically now everywhere I'd have to switch back and forth using implicits and it's completely unmanagable. Can anyone think of an alternate definition of `Universal` such that *at least* `Adapter[t.Self] <:< Universal[t.Super]` and `Adapter[t.Super] <:< Universal[t.Super]`, but preferably one which encompasses all wrappers with `a.thing.Self <: T` for arbitrary `T` (because I don't even have a `T <: Thing` in the place where I need this subtyping to work). I don't know, type lambdas, braking it into partial type definitions to somehow manually enforce transitiveness?

Comment: Are you sure that actually _should_ compile? And can't it be minimized further? This looks really complicated while a lot of that stuff doesn't seem to be directly related to the actual issue.

Comment: I don't like this part `type Super >: Self <: Thing {type Super <: thisThing.Super}`. `thisThing.Super` is a subtype of a refinement of `Thing` where the `Super` inside that refinement is again a subtype of `thisThing.Super` instead of being a supertype. Is that because you want to make sure they're equal? Because there's probably an easier way to do it

Comment: Using `thing.Self` for `Adapter` inside `Universal` [works](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/gPvfbpmVRNC8JYu8FGzVfQ), by the way.

Comment: 1). @Jasper-M: no, I thing it is minimal as it is. Any arguments why this is illegal? The issue is that the information about `Self <: Super` in `Thing#Super` is lost because the repeated bound in the refinement does not contain it. And it does not contain it, because then either a) we repeat `type Super  >: Self <: thisThing.Super; type Self <: thisThing.Super` and get an illegal cyclic dependency error, or b) have `type Super <: thisThing.Super; type Self <: Super` and then we get (an erronous) override error of Adapter[_]#Super.

Comment: 1) Can't see anything wrong with that: Thing#Super is an isomorphism which maps to either an equal type or a subtype. For almost all classes in my case, it is identity. But there is a class which has `this.Super = Thing` and thus `this.Super.Super <: this.Super`. 2) And I am aware that using `Adapter[thing.Self]` works. The problem is that a part of established API requires an argument of `this.Super`, which in adapter's case is `Adapter[thing.Super]`. Even if I produce only instances of `Adapter[thing.Self]`, it will always ask for `Adapter[thing.Super]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I eventually did is I reversed the dependency. Instead of

```
 type Universal[+T <: Thing] = Adapter { type Adapted <: T }
```

(or similar), I added more member types to `Thing`:

```
trait Thing { thisThing =>
    /* as before */
    type Adapt = Wrapper { 
        type SuperAdapted <: thisThing.Super 
    }
    type AdaptSuper = Wrapper {
        type SuperAdapted = thisThing.Super
        type Adapted = thisThing.Self
    }
}
```

where the type `SuperAdapted` was ommitted from the original question in minimizing, but is required in my actual problem:

```
trait Adapter[+T <: Thing] {
    /* as before */
    type SuperAdapted = thing.Super
}
```

Now, instead of bounds `[T <: Thing, A <: Universal[T]]` and passing `[t.Super, Adapter[Super]]` I have `[T <: Thing, A <: T#AdaptSuper]` (or `[T <: Thing, A <: T#Adapt]`, depending on the use case). It is not as flexible or elegant as before, but works and fits my use cases. That is, until Scala 3...

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand the logic encoded in types completely but shouldn't it be

```
trait Thing { thisThing =>
  type Super >: Self <: Thing {
    type Super <: thisThing.Super
    type Self = thisThing.Self
  }
  type Self <: Thing {
    type Super = thisThing.Super
    type Self = thisThing.Self
  }
}
```

https://scastie.scala-lang.org/KW1woPxLSoywdJPj779bPA

or

```
trait Thing { thisThing =>
  type Super >: Self <: Thing {
    type Super >: thisThing.Self/*instead of Self*/ <: thisThing.Super   
    type Self <: thisThing.Super
  }
  type Self <: Thing {
    type Super = thisThing.Super
    type Self = thisThing.Self
  }
}
```

https://scastie.scala-lang.org/QfV5f3RxScW29w7Kv0d6qA

?

Comment: I'm not sure the first one would work, because the `Self` type of `Super` has to be a supertype of `this.Self` and can't be equal to it.

Comment: @user How do you check this? What doesn't compile if we take `type Self = thisThing.Self`?

Comment: It just seemed odd to me logically, and I had an example with a trait `Foo` extending `Thing` and `Bar` extending `Foo` and I couldn't get it to work. Let me find it

Comment: And these compile for you? Ad 1: this won't work. the Thing => Thing#Super morphism is not lossless. Think of it: you upcast a class `Specific { type Super = Base; type Self = Specific }` to some base class `Base { type Super = Base }`. Now `Base#Self` is unspecified, we only know that `Base#Self <: Base#Super`, violating the refinement of `Specific#Super`. Ad 2: It would work. Except I get an `illegal cyclic dependency involving type Super` when I try it and could not work around it in any way.

Comment: Nvm, I didn't notice the `>: thisThing.Self` instead of `>: Self`. Unfortunately it won't work for that special case of `Unit { type Super = Thing }` I have and which is central to the whole design. Having these bounds, one might as well have `type Super <: Thing { type Super = thisThing.Super }`.