# Scala Trait Returning a Sub-type?

Tags: scala, inheritance, typeclass, f-bounded-polymorphism

Given a trait:

```
@ trait Foo {
    def withStuffAdded(str: String): Foo
  } 
defined trait Foo
```

I then defined a sub-class of `Foo`:

```
@ class X(val str: String) extends Foo { 
    override def withStuffAdded(s: String): Foo = new X(str + s)
  } 
defined class X
```

Finally, I tried to define this function:

```
@ def something(x: X): X = x.withStuffAdded("something") 
cmd3.sc:1: type mismatch;
 found   : ammonite.$sess.cmd1.Foo
 required: ammonite.$sess.cmd2.X
def something(x: X): X = x.withStuffAdded("something")
                                         ^
Compilation Failed
```

The compiler fails as it expected a `Foo` to be returned, not an `X`.

How can I change the definition of `Foo#withStuffAdded` to compile, i.e. return a sub-type of `Foo` in the type signature?

Comment: Ding ding ding, that is a FAQ: https://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/index.html#how-can-a-method-in-a-superclass-return-a-value-of-the-current-type

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3962219/mytype-problem-do-i-have-to-use-abstract-types-or-generics-in-scala-to-retu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Luis' comment is perfectly valid. I'll try explaining how to arrive to the solution mentioned in the comment.

If I got this right, you are actually interested in having the subclass as a result type in the subclass' method, but since your trait definition does not allow it, you are forced to return a `Foo` in method `withStuffAdded` of class `X`.

Although not obvious, this sounds like a code smell. Perhaps an abstract type is what are you looking for to begin with, to loosen up the design and allow your requirement to comply:

```
trait Foo {
  type T <: Foo

  def withStuffAdded(str: String): T
}

class X(val str: String) extends Foo {
  type T = X

  override def withStuffAdded(s: String): X = new X(str + s)
}
```

Now this will work:

```
def something(x: X): X = x.withStuffAdded("something")
```

Although a flexible design, from here on, it becomes clearer that in order to further improve on it, possible solutions include either using f-bounded polymorphism or a typeclass.

I would probably be inclined to use a typeclass as this is the functional way. What you'll need depends on your requirements, but either will work.

Comment: “Although not obvious, this sounds like a code smell” Thanks, Luis, for your answer. I agree with you but could you say more, please, on why it’s a smell?

Comment: I wouldn't say is a code smell, this a recurring problem, and one that sadly doesn't have a great answer. Curiously, just yesterday we were discussing in the **Discord** server why the language doesn't expose a `Self` type for this case - BTW Alin, using that type parameter is actually a weaker encoding of F-Bound polymorphism :)

Comment: Yes, it's more of a recurring problem. I said a code smell in the sense that it forces you to "live with it" in the subclass,  so it's "smelling" in the subclass, although the real issue is actually in the superclass. And yes, Luis, it is weaker intentional. It was meant as a how-to arrive to the final solution. As mentioned it can and should be improved further.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez *"why the language doesn't expose a Self type for this case"* It's not obvious how precise `Self` should be for all use cases. If you have `trait A { type T; type T1; ...; def m(); def m1(); ...}` should `Self` for `SubA` be just `SubA` or `SubA {type T=...; type T1=...; ...}`? For all type members or some of them? Should it be structural `SubA {def m(); def m1(); ...}`? For some members or all of them? Should `Self` be F-bounded `SubA {type Self = SubA}`, `SubA {type Self = SubA {type Self = SubA}}` ,`SubA {type Self = self.Self}`?

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Should it be an abstract `type Self >: this.type <: SubA`, `type Self >: this.type <: SubA {type Self >: this.type <: SubA}`...?

Comment: @DmytroMitin I am not saying it is an easy task, but it may be doable. Also, it seems it was actually proposed a couple of times; although more as a replacement for typeclasses _(which IMHO is what lead to it not being considered)_. Also, AFAIK `this.type` simply erases to the class `SubA` so I would say your last proposal makes all the sense.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez I meant not that the task is hard but that desired outcome can be different for different people in different use cases https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64081068/is-there-a-pattern-trick-to-enforce-when-defining-type-aliases-with  *"Also, AFAIK `this.type` simply erases to the class `SubA`"* During erasure it does https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/03-types.html#type-erasure  but before that they are quite different types and we can organize type-level calculations based on that and this can lead to different runtime behavior.